# R - String labels to numeric

Tags: r

I have data consisting of three classes which are represented by strings. I need to change these to numeric and represent them as e.g academic,general -> 0, and vocation -> 1.
I will then apply logistic regression and create a classifier. Are there any quick ways of doing this?
Thanks :)

Example of data where prog is the value to predict(y):
[image: Prog is the y value]

Update: Print from dput

```
structure(list(prog = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("general", "academic", "vocation"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("male", 
    "female"), class = "factor"), math = c(50, 51, 57, 72, 41, 
    58, 58, 53, 51, 38), science = c(31, 47, 55, 61, 42, 59, 
    74, 61, 53, 47), socst = c(56, 61, 51, 61, 51, 56, 66, 51, 
    37, 41)), .Names = c("prog", "sex", "math", "science", "socst"
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse` or `merge` depends on your data. Please share a reproducible example of your dataset.

Comment: Added example of the data

Comment: Please do not share your example dataset through screenshot. Use `dput` and paste the output to here..

Comment: I hope that's better

Comment: Don't convert it to numeric, convert it to factor and apply regression right on it

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see right away there were 2 values to group as 0. Then `lkp<-data.frame(prog=c('academic', 'general','vocation'),n=c(0,0,1));merge(df,lkp)`

Comment: To convert as factor you'd have done `df$prog = factor(df$prog)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

Use `ifelse`

```
dt2 <- dt
dt2$Class <- ifelse(dt2$prog %in% c("academic", "general"), 0, 1)

dt2
       prog    sex math science socst Class
1  academic   male   50      31    56     0
2  vocation female   51      47    61     1
3  academic   male   57      55    51     0
4  academic female   72      61    61     0
5  academic   male   41      42    51     0
6  academic female   58      59    56     0
7   general   male   58      74    66     0
8  academic female   53      61    51     0
9  vocation female   51      53    37     1
10 academic   male   38      47    41     0
```

Or use `merge`

```
class_df <- data.frame(prog = c("academic", "general", "vocation"),
                       Class = c(0, 0, 1),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt3 <- merge(dt, class_df, by = "prog", all.x = TRUE)
dt3
       prog    sex math science socst Class
1  academic   male   50      31    56     0
2  academic female   58      59    56     0
3  academic   male   57      55    51     0
4  academic female   72      61    61     0
5  academic   male   41      42    51     0
6  academic   male   38      47    41     0
7  academic female   53      61    51     0
8   general   male   58      74    66     0
9  vocation female   51      53    37     1
10 vocation female   51      47    61     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way to do what you're asking.

```
data = structure(list(prog = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                     2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("general", "academic", "vocation"), class = "factor"), 
                  sex = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("male", 
                                                                                        "female"), class = "factor"), 
                  math = c(50, 51, 57, 72, 41, 58, 58, 53, 51, 38), 
                  science = c(31, 47, 55, 61, 42, 59, 74, 61, 53, 47), 
                  socst = c(56, 61, 51, 61, 51, 56, 66, 51, 37, 41)), 
             .Names = c("prog", "sex", "math", "science", "socst"), 
             row.names = c(NA, 10L), 
             class = "data.frame")
data$progBIN = ifelse(data$prog == "vocation",1,0)
```

You can create a new column called progBIN which will hold the binary label.  You set this by checking if `data$prog` is 'vocation' - if it is, return a 1, otherwise return a 0.

Actually - this can be even easier.

```
data$progBIN = data$prog == "vocation"
```

Since your positive class involves only one of the three labels you can do a logical check (`data$prog == "vocation"`) and store that in a new column.  Because logical TRUEs are equivalent in R to a numeric 1 and a logical FALSE is equivalent to a numeric 0, R will convert upward if needed.

What if the case were reversed and Vocation needed to be 0 with the other two being a 1?

```
data$progBIN = data$prog != "vocation"
```

What if you had 4 labels and two defined your positive class?

```
data$progBIN = data$prog %in% c('class1','class2')
```